# Invalid conversion from int* to int using functions

Tags: c, function, variables

I have this "simple" problem: I have in input 2 int numbers and i must output them in decreasing order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int fnum()
{
    int NUM;
    scanf("%d",&NUM);
    return NUM;
}

void frisultato(int x,int y)
{
    if (x>y)
    {
            printf("%d",x);
            printf("%d",y);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("%d",y);
            printf("%d",x);
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{    
      int A,B;     
      A=fnum;
      B=fnum;

      frisultato(A,B);
}
```

I recieve an error at

```
A=fnum;
B=fnum;
```

my compiler says: invalid conversion from int(*)() to int.

This is the first time i use functions, what is the problem? Thank you!

- Michelangelo.

Comment: `A=fnum;` come on...

Comment: `A=fnum()`. `fnum` is the function itself. `()` is the call operator: call what's to the left wih no arguments. So to get from function to function result you apply the call operator: `fnum  ()` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  A=fnum;
  B=fnum;
```

You're not actually calling the function `fnum` here.  You're attempting to assign a pointer to the function to the `int` variables `A` and `B`.

To call the function, do this:

```
  A=fnum();
  B=fnum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but since you seem to be new at programming, I couldn't help but refactor/comment on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int fnum()
{
    int num; 
    scanf("%d",&num);
    return num;
}

void frisultato(int x, int y)
{
    if (x>y)
    {
        printf("%d",x);
        printf("%d",y);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",y);
        printf("%d",x);
    }

    /* No need to return in void */
}

int main()
{    

    /*
        Variables in C are all lowercase. 

        UPPER_CASE is usually used for macros and preprocessor directives
        such as 

        #define PI 3.14 
    */
    int a, b;
    a = fnum(); //Function calls always need parenthesis, even if they are empty
    b = fnum();

    frisultato(a, b);

    /*
        Your main function should return an integer letting whoever 
        ran it know if it was successful or not. 

        0 means everything went well, anything else means something went wrong.
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Also, don't sign your name on StackOverflow questions.